# Where is Rodney Waddler?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, geography

My friend Rodney Waddler is currently travelling around Europe. Over the course of eight days, he intends to visit eight different European capital cities - one each day.

On Day 1, Rodney sent me the itinerary for his trip, along with a photo of him standing on the aeroplane stairs before boarding, captioned "Here's a clue!" - I figured this meant I should interpret the listed triplets as three-letter [IATA airport codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IATA_airport_code), but some of them represent airports that are outside of Europe or don't exist at all!

I'm totally stumped - how can I work out which cities he's visiting? (And how on earth does he expect me to work out where he is on Day 1 - he's given me nothing to work with at all?!) Perhaps you can help me...

> **TASK: Identify the eight European capital cities that Rodney is visiting, with a step-by-step explanation of how these can be deduced.**

| Day | Itinerary |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | → |
| 2 | → GRV → |
| 3 | → JLT → MTH → |
| 4 | → CVR → FFR → CRT → |
| 5 | → SCK → LRG → PRN → JSH → |
| 6 | → PLS → WRT → QVQ → DSH → MRN → |
| 7 | → MNT → DLL → LGM → HVN → RGG → NMD → |
| 8 | → DND → PCH → PST → FSS → PLS → WTH → STP → |

**Hint 1:**

> I've been very formal in this write-up, calling my friend by his full first name throughout - but I usually shorten it...

**Hint 2:** (to share a remark made in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair))

> After a short conversation with Rod, I received [confirmation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58395340#58395340) that these letter triplets are definitely *not* IATA airport codes - he just wrote this 'itinerary' in such a way as to resemble them. So now I'm thinking I definitely need to do something to each triplet to make them 'readable'...

Comment: Cairo -- obviously... theres a pyramid! ;D

Comment: Maybe a dead end (and everyone who's tackled this beforehand probably already noticed it), but rot13(Abar bs gur pbqrf pbagnva ibjryf, juvpu vf xvaq bs hahfhny fvapr VNGN pbqrf pna irel jryy pbagnva gurz. Lbh pna znxr fbzr jbeqf ol vafregvat ibjryf (creuncf k ibjryf jurer k vf gur nzbhag qrabgrq ol gur yrsg ahzore va gur ebj), ohg gurl qba'g nccrne gb cebqhpr nal pburerag cuenfrf.)

Comment: V jebgr n cebtenz gb bhgchg rirel ebg-a naq fuvsg-a. Ng yrnfg bar pbqr unf ab inyvq fuvsgf gb na nvecbeg naq ebg-a qvqa'g frrz gb pbagnva nal cnggreaf. DID frrzf gb ehyr bhg yrggre vafregvba. Fb ab yhpx. Gur ulcuraf va gur grkg ner bqqyl cynprq naq gur cerprqvat yrggref fcryy 'frrq 1'.

Comment: @Amoz Ha, the 'seed 1' reference is unintentional and has no bearing on this puzzle, I'm afraid :)

Comment: Ofwfs njoe xibu J tbje bcpvu RWR; J hvftt uifsf jt FRVJWPRVF. Cvu uif sftu ibwf b mpu npsf nbudift up tpsu uispvhi, jg uijt jt uif sjhiu ejsfdujpo.

Comment: rot13(Gurer nera'g znal yrggref gb nanylmr, ohg gur serdhrapl bs pbafbanagf qbrf va snpg ebhtuyl zngpu gur serdhrapl lbh jbhyq rkcrpg va n grkg / va qvpgvbanel jbeqf. Vs guvf vf gur snpr, gurer fubhyq or fbzrguvat gryyvat hf juvpu ibjryf gb vafreg naq jurer gb vafreg, ohg vg frrzf yvxr gurer'f abg zhpu ninvynoyr...)

Comment: rot13(Naq whfg nabgure gubhtug (fbeel sbe fcnzzvat), vs L vf nyfb gerngrq nf n ibjry (ab Lf va grkg), Ebqarl zvtug or fubegrarq gb EQA vafgrnq bs r.t. "Ebq", naq fbzrubj trggvat onpx sebz EQA gb Ebqarl hanzovthbhfyl zvtug or gur fnzr zrgubq hfrq sbe gur bgure pbqrf. Nyfb, guerr yrggref qba'g arprffnevyl unir gb cebqhpr bar jbeq, vs jr unir NOP QRS gur qrpelcgrq sbez jvgu ibjryf zvtug or r.t. NiO PiQiR Si)

Comment: V nterr; V gevrq fhofgvghgvat pbhagel be pvgl anzrf ohg vg oernxf qbja nebhaq ebj 6 hayrff gur ehyrf trg zber pbzcyrk.
Ncneg sebz gung gurer ner gbb znal bcgvbaf, jr arrq fbzrguvat gb svygre gurz qbja. V gubhtug znlor gur -> vaqvpngrf 'bireynccvat punenpgre' juvpu jbhyq qrsvavgryl qb gur gevpx... ohg nccylvat gung gb ebj 6 penfurq jura V tbg gb "QFU", pna'g svaq n jbeq.
NCYLFVN be NCYNFVN > NJNEHVGR > RDHVIBDHR > ????

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The capitals Rodney visits are ...

> ... **London**, **Madrid**, **Warsaw**, **Lisbon**, **Zagreb**, **Prague**, **Tirana** and **Athens**.

How?

> Lukas and Amoz have made some useful observations in the comments: All three-letter codes in the message consist of consonants only. The consonants have a fairly regular distribution that about matches letter distribution in actual words.
>
>  These codes can be expanded with vowels only to get English words. Those words have a three-letter synonym. For example DND → *dined* → **ate**; PCH → epoch → **age**; PST → *past* → **ago**. Each synonym differs from the previous one by one letter.

What's with the "aeroplane stairs"?

> That's a hint towards **word ladders**, of course. And my friend's name, ROD WADDLER, is an anagram of WORD LADDER.

And the cities?

> There are now eight independent chains. Each can be extended at the front and the back to give two three-letter parts of a capital. (Ever notice how so many capitals in Europe have six letters?)
>
>  For example, the last chain starts with **ate** and ends with **end**, from which we can make ATH → **ate** → ... → **end** → ENS: **Athens**. The first day has only one step from the first part to the last part. This must be **London**.

In detail:

> ```
>                 LON
>                 DON -- London, United Kingdom
>
>                 MAD
> GRV groovy      RAD
>                 RID -- Madrid, Spain
>
>                 WAR
> JLT jolt        JAR
> MTH mouth       JAW
>                 SAW -- Warsaw, Poland
>
>
>                 LIS
> CVR cover       LID
> FFR offer       BID
> CRT crate       BIN
>                 BON -- Lisbon, Portugal
>
>
>                 ZAG
> SCK sack        BAG
> LRG large       BIG
> PRN apron       BIB
> JSH josh        RIB
>                 REB -- Zagreb, Croatia
>
>
>                 PRA
> PLS pulse       PEA
> WRT write       PEN
> QVQ equivoque   PUN
> DSH dash        RUN
> MRN mourn       RUE
>                 GUE -- Prague, Czechia
>
>
>
>                 TIR
> MNT mount       TOR
> DLL doll        TOY
> LGM legume      SOY
> HVN heaven      SKY
> RGG reggae      SKA
> NMD named       AKA
>                 ANA -- Tirana, Albania
>
>                 ATH
> DND dined       ATE
> PCH epoch       AGE
> PST past        AGO
> FSS fuss        ADO
> PLS plus        ADD
> WTH with        AND
> STP stop        END
>                 ENS -- Athens, Greece
> ```

Comment: You are within touching distance of the true mechanism here (+1 for spotting what the itineraries actually shroud)! You have correctly identified one of the city-day combinations at present, and have named another correct city on an incorrect day... Take another look at Day 8 - you have all intermediate steps correct on that one... but IATA codes are *not* involved at all. Think more about the city you have already correctly attached to that day... hopefully things will become clearer then!

Comment: (You also have all intermediate words correct on Days 5 and 6 - once you crack 8 entirely, you should be able to crack those next! To confirm other translations that need changing: groove, court and amount are not the intended triplet translations; and Day 3's synonyms need different words...)

Comment: Ha! And I thought I was being clever here. I also thought of rot13(guerr-yrggre pbhagel pbqrf), but couldn't make it fit, but now I see rot13(EHF naq RAT).

Comment: You really are very closely to nobbling this! There's an 'aha' moment ready to jump up and strike you! Look at the first and last words on Day 8... I'll leave it at that for now!

Comment: Ah! (That was the first part of the Aha! moment.)

Comment: Oh, I have it now, but I need to do some "legwork".

Comment: Great work :) Very nearly there! Your bevowelled word on Day 2 is not what I intended (clue: I was counting Y as a vowel here...) and you'll get a different city when you find that one, and Day 3's synonyms (and city) are still not the ones I had in mind. But you've cracked Days 4-8 and found Day 1, well done! Considering the list of possibilities, can you spot my intentions for Days 2 and 3?

Comment: Well, not super happy with my "jolt" synonym, but here goes ...

Comment: Ohf, you are *so close* to wrapping this up! Can you spot a different starting letter that satisfies both synonyms in a more satisfying way (for the first one)? The city is correct. One last remark from me - can you see the relevance of Rod's name? There was another hint hidden there! :)

Comment: Okay, that was ... jarring. I had tried to make somthing from Rad's name, but the only thing I can see in his abbreviated name is that I can make rot13(ZNQ > Jnq + Ebq > EVQ) from it. Or of course, something RED, rot13(n ureevat, creuncf)?

Comment: Well done :) I'm awarding you the checkmark for this great solution. However, if you happen to spot the significance of ROD WADDLER at any point, please do add it in at a relevant point... Thanks!